# Convert bitmap to gray scale and keep transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-7.0

Can you advise me how to **ensure transparency after conversion to grayscale** in the case of a wpf c# application and resource image in png format programmatically?

I created a **minimal working project to test**, you can find it here: [Github GrayTransparencyTest](https://github.com/atiris/GrayTransparencyTest)

**Edit 2**: Github repository has been updated to the first two solutions from users "Just Answer the Question" and "Clemens". Transparency is preserved even if the conversion to grayscale looks slightly different from the xaml.

The problem looks like this (now including first 2 solutions):
[image: Result]
*I need the 4th image to retain the transparency of the original image after converting to grayscale.*

Using XAML everything works:

```xml
<Image>
  <Image.Source>
    <FormatConvertedBitmap DestinationFormat="Gray16">
      <FormatConvertedBitmap.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/GrayTransparencyTest;component/Media/priority.png" />
      </FormatConvertedBitmap.Source>
    </FormatConvertedBitmap>
  </Image.Source>
  <Image.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush>
      <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/GrayTransparencyTest;component/Media/priority.png" />
      </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
    </ImageBrush>
  </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

Using binding Image and C# methods for `FormatConvertedBitmap`, no chance:

```cs
string imageKey = "priority";
Uri imageURI = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/GrayTransparencyTest;component/Media/{imageKey}.png", UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(imageURI);
ImageBrush opacityMask = new ImageBrush()
{
  ImageSource = bitmapImage
};
FormatConvertedBitmap bitmapGreyscale = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
bitmapGreyscale.BeginInit();
bitmapGreyscale.Source = new BitmapImage(imageURI);
bitmapGreyscale.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray16;
bitmapGreyscale.EndInit();
ImageGray = new Image()
{
  Source = bitmapGreyscale,
  OpacityMask = opacityMask,
};
```

It looks like OpacityMask is not working. How is it possible to add transparency to Image please? Can you advise if this `OpacityMask = opacityMask` is really not supposed to work the way I expected it to, or how I would fix it to work like it does in XAML? (workaround: grayscale versions of images direct as resources).

According to the answers so far it looks like it can't be done other than by directly editing the bitmap pixels of the image. So far no one has explained to me why the original code does not work.

Comment: It certainly can be done but you might have to do the grayscale conversion yourself byte by byte. If that's of interest I can provide more details.

Comment: Hi @just-answer-the-question, sure, I'm interested in how to solve this. Would it be a Bitmap modification from the System.Drawing namespace? Because just the correct conversion between BitmapImage and Bitmap is not trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution without System.Drawing.Bitmap and GDI.

It creates a new BitmapSource from the grayscale-converted buffer of the original BitmapSource that keeps the alpha channel. The code works for the usual `PixelFormats.Bgra32` and `PixelFormats.Pbgra32` formats, but could easily be adapted to other formats.

```
public static BitmapSource ConvertToGrayscale(BitmapSource source)
{
    var stride = (source.PixelWidth * source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    var pixels = new byte[stride * source.PixelWidth];

    source.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
    {
        // this works for PixelFormats.Bgra32
        var blue = pixels[i];
        var green = pixels[i + 1];
        var red = pixels[i + 2];
        var gray = (byte)(0.2126 * red + 0.7152 * green + 0.0722 * blue);
        pixels[i] = gray;
        pixels[i + 1] = gray;
        pixels[i + 2] = gray;
    }

    return BitmapSource.Create(
        source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight,
        source.DpiX, source.DpiY,
        source.Format, null, pixels, stride);
}
```

Use it like this:

```
ImageGray = new Image { Source = ConvertToGrayscale(bitmapImage) };
```

Comment: Your answer works without any modifications, thanks.

Comment: Yes I considered this method but it requires an entire extra copy of the bitmap to be made in RAM so is not as efficient as manipulating the buffer directly using GDI+.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it I'm not sure this is less efficient as LockBits also has to make a copy. I think efficiency might depend on if the native image is living in VRAM as a D3D surface or system RAM. Absolute best would be to make your own shader but I'm not going down that rabbit hole. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if there's a more simple or efficient way of doing this, but if you're not afraid of some low-level image manipulation this should do the trick. It will return a `BitmapSource` given a stream representing your PNG file, which you can obtain whether it's an embedded resource or whatnot. Auxiliary methods:

```cs
using SysDraw = System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// update Image property
ImageGray = new Image()
{
  Source = GetTransparentGrayscale(imageUri)
};
// conversion resource to stream
public ImageSource? GetTransparentGrayscale(Uri imageUri)
{
  StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);
  ImageSource? imageSource = default;
  if (sri != null)
  {
    using (Stream s = sri.Stream)
    {
      imageSource = ConvertToTransparentGrayscale(s);
    }
  }
  return imageSource;
}
// delete GDI object method
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);
```

Method for conversion png stream to grayscale:

```cs
public static unsafe ImageSource? ConvertToTransparentGrayscale(Stream png)
{
    SysDraw.Bitmap? bmp = SysDraw.Bitmap.FromStream(png) as SysDraw.Bitmap;
    if (bmp == null) { return null; }
    SysDraw.Imaging.BitmapData bits = bmp.LockBits(
        new SysDraw.Rectangle(0, 0, (int)bmp.Width, (int)bmp.Height),
        SysDraw.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        SysDraw.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    byte* buf = (byte*)bits.Scan0;
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            int offset = y * bits.Stride + x * 4;
            byte gray = (byte)(0.2126 * buf[offset + 2] + 0.7152 * buf[offset + 1] + 0.0722 * buf[offset]);
            buf[offset + 1] = gray; // blue channel
            buf[offset + 2] = gray; // green channel
            buf[offset] = gray; // red channel
        }
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
    IntPtr hBmp = bmp.GetHbitmap();
    try
    {
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBmp,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally { DeleteObject(hBmp); }
}
```

*Note: Values for conversion to gray are common, but it is possible that it will be necessary to adjust them for your case.*

Comment: Hi, I have reviewed, edited and adapted your answer and applied it to my requirements. It is indeed possible to create a transparent grayscale image from the original in this way. Until there is a better solution, I will accept this as well. Well thank you.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the edits and glad this worked for you.

Comment: This answer still solves the problem, thanks, but Clemens's solution is preferable for now. I've included everything in the question and the github repository.